# Can't see class-level variables when debugging in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm observing some odd behavior while debugging some C# code in VS 2013. When I hover over any variables scoped to the current method, I can see the variable's information. In the screenshot below, you can see that ivSimulation is pinned and showing information. However, even though you can't tell, I had the mouse over `this._simulator` and nothing shows up. QuickWatch shows nothing either.

[image]

Another coworker is also having this same issue. We've tried wiping our folders clean and getting the latest again. And we've also tried changing a setting in VS (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Use Managed Compatibility Mode) to being checked, but that hasn't worked either. Apparently that has worked for others. This was working just fine in VS 2012.

Any ideas? How can I get the class-level variables to show in the debugger?

**Edit: Another piece of the puzzle**

If I hover over `this` I see that it is a transparent proxy. Not sure why that would happen.

[image]

Another piece:

`this` refers to a class that derives from `ContextBoundObject`. We do that so we can use interception for logging and exception handling. Perhaps that is the reason.

And I was wrong; this isn't working in VS2012. Perhaps I just never noticed it before.

If I try to display the value in the immediate window, this is what I get:

> ? this._coater.Equipment.Line.Unit.Plant.Site.SiteId Cannot obtain
>   fields or call methods on the instance of type
>   'Company.Mes.Core.Components.Logic.ModuleDerating.StandardDeratingComponentLogic'
>   because it is a proxy to a remote object.

Comment: I have no idea if it would help at all, but clear your Shadow Cache

Comment: Can you see the contents of `this._simulator` in the watch window?

Comment: @AngeloGeels I just posted some new evidence in my question. So, no, I can't see the contents. (If watch window and immediate window mean the same thing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `this` is a transparent proxy.

The following screenshots demonstrate this issue given the sample code at the bottom.

First creating the real object and hovering over that instance's `Name` property:

[image]

Now create a proxy for the object.
[image]

*Notice I hover over the instance to show it is a transparent proxy.*

Now hover over the `Name` property of the transparent proxy instance.
[image]

Nothing shows up! The transparent proxy does a clever marshaling of the calls to the underlying object but the IDE clearly isn't able to figure it out since the returned proxy object is a dynamically generated class based on the `Foo` class.

And the output for completeness.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo(){ Name = "My Foo1" };

            Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);

            FooProxy fooProxy = new FooProxy(foo);

            Foo proxiedFoo = (Foo)fooProxy.GetTransparentProxy();

            Console.WriteLine(proxiedFoo.Name);
        }
    }

    public class Foo : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooProxy 
        : RealProxy
    {
        private Foo _target;

        public FooProxy(Foo target) : base(typeof(Foo))
        {
            this._target = target;
        }

        public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
        {
            return InvokeRemoteCall((IMethodCallMessage)msg, this._target);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes the remote call.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="methodCall">The method call.</param>
        /// <param name="target">The target.</param>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="ReturnMessage"/></returns>
        private static IMessage InvokeRemoteCall(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, object target)
        {
            MethodInfo method = methodCall.MethodBase as MethodInfo;

            object callResult = (target != null) ? method.Invoke(target, methodCall.InArgs) : null;

            LogicalCallContext context = methodCall.LogicalCallContext;

            var query = method.GetParameters().Where(param => ((ParameterInfo)param).IsOut);

            ParameterInfo[] outParameters = query.ToArray();

            return new ReturnMessage(callResult, outParameters, outParameters.Count(), context, methodCall);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be that *this._simulator* is assigned but not used anywhere (yet), so the debugger optimize this and not show those variables.

If that is the case, just try to for example after the assignation use the ToString() method and then put the break point after it.

```
...
this._simulator = GetEquipment(ivSimulation);
this._simulator.ToString();
//Another line with the break point here
```